# How to use unpublished package in React?

Tags: reactjs

How to use unpublished package in React project?

I have module in my local and is yet to publish, how can I use this in my React project?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-all-data

I have did some changes in package in my local and have created `country-all-data-1.0.7.tgz`,
Now want to use above file as a node_module in react project

Comment: `npm link`, maybe? It's unclear what your situation actually is.

Comment: you can also install it locally like `npm install ../../place/to/you/package`

Comment: Thank you @PRSHL, It worked "npm install ../path/country-all-data-1.0.7.tgz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an archive file with `npm pack`.
Then go to react project and `run npm install ../path/to/archive/file`.
This adds the module into node_modules directory.

STEP 1: In module project, execute npm pack:
This will build a -.tar.gz file.

```
e.g. country-all-data-1.0.7.tgz
```

STEP 2: Move the above file to the react project

STEP 3: npm install country-all-data-1.0.7.tgz

**Or**

STEP 1: Refer it in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
          "country-all-data": "file:country-all-data-1.0.7.tgz"
        }
```

STEP 2: npm install

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json add the local path of your tgz (you can also move tgz to your project directory and use relative path)

```
    {
      ...
      "dependencies": {
        ...
        "package-name": 'path/package.tgz',
        ...
      }
    }
```